# about Python Django Administration page's appearance

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner of python Django .i created a django administration page but it was some problem with css.[this is the screen shot of the that page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAQAi.png).i want to be that  like this. [this is the what i wanted page's screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nvLz.png). anyone can help me?

Comment: Can you view the source of that page and see if the .css is loaded?

Comment: Did you put your screen on a copy machine?

Comment: i can't view all of the source codes .because that is too much characters  can i have your mail to send source code i cant recognize clearly source codes.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command first:

```
 python manage.py collectstatic
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to test your django project, check your `setting.py` file, change `DEBUG` to `True`, then run `manage.py runserver`, and you'll see what you want at `localhost:8000/admin` Admin interface.

If your django project is ready for deployment, run `python manage.py collectstatic` and manage.py will automatically collect static files (css, js ...) for you.